# Webform Individual Type not saving

Tags: webform-civicrm

I'm trying to set the following setting:

Type of Individual

However, everytime I try to save it I get the following error message:

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in wf_crm_get_fields() (line 910 of /home3/isrcus/public_html/sites/all/modules/webform_civicrm/includes/utils.inc).

Is there a reason I keep getting that error messsage?

Thanks!
Kevin

Comment: d7 or d8? may make a difference

Comment: Are you using Cases?